# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException in Robolectric 2.4

Tags: android, robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I have trouble loading resources when running unit tests from command line. It works fine in IntelliJ.

I'm using:

- com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3
- org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:1.0.1
- org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4

I have the following project structure (Multi-module):

```
+---module1
|   |   build.gradle
    |   \---src
    |       +---main
    |       |   |   AndroidManifest.xml
    |       |   |   
    |       |   +---res
    |       |   |   \---values
    |       |   |           strings.xml
    |       \---test
    |           \---java
    |               \---example
    |                    |   FooTest.java
+---module2
etc
```

My test (simplified) looks like this:

```
@Config(emulateSdk = 18, reportSdk = 18, manifest = "./src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class FooTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        String result = Robolectric.application.getString(R.string.error_message);

         assertThat(result, notNullValue());
    }
 }
```

I get this stacktrace:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: unknown resource 2131361826
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAssetManager.getAndResolve(ShadowAssetManager.java:311)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAssetManager.getResourceText(ShadowAssetManager.java:69)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceText(AssetManager.java)
at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:235)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.getText(ShadowResources.java:363)
at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java)
at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:325)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowContext.getString(ShadowContext.java:41)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowContextWrapper.getString(ShadowContextWrapper.java:96)
at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java)
```

**Note**: I'm quite new to Gradle so it is likely that there is a misconfiguration somewhere. I have assumed that by following the project structure convention that I don't need to specify where to find resources. I tried specifying them but without any luck:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try to change your config manifest to `module1/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`. It is not fix for your issue (now you will probably have failing tests in AS) but just quick check the problem

Comment: Hi, I tried and got this:

> File '/opt/buildagent/work/22b7e45eb23ab445/module1/module1/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml' specified for property 'manifest' does not exist.

Comment: Wrong guess. Can you remove mentioning of the manifest file in config at all?

Comment: Another question what version of android gradle plugin do you have?

Comment: @EugenMartynov Same error when removing the line `            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'` 

I've updated the post with the gradle android plugin version!

Comment: Clear! Last question - does your debug build changes applicationId? like adding ".debug" or something?

Comment: With android gradle 1.1.x you can remove usage of gradle robolectric plugin

Comment: Removing the robolectric gradle plugin solved my problem. Please post an answer so that I can mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During investigation we found the cause of problem. If you use `android gradle plugin v1.1.x` then you don't need in common `robolectric gradle plugin`.

Be carefull that incorrect version of `robolectric gradle plugin` will break your tests.